# How can I make 2 apps (1 local, 1 containerized) reach another container without using the service name (docker-compose)?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm relatively new to Docker, so I apologize if this is silly but I can't find a good answer in my digging about. I've got a Django (python) web app service (container named 'app') that I need to talk to the database service (container named 'db').

I'm trying to set this up so I can just run the `python manage.py runserver` command locally *or* fire up the `app` container to run the application without having to change my `.env` file in order to point the `HOST` variable to a different location.

My .env file looks like this:

```
DB_ENCRYPT_CONNECTIONS=no
DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE=yes
DB_ENGINE=mssql
NAME=myapp
HOST=localhost
USER=sa
PASSWORD=<super_pass_here>
PORT=1433
```

When I have `localhost` as the `HOST` - the `app` container won't resolve to the container `db`; I get why, but having it as `localhost` is useful for when I'm developing locally and before running it in the `app` container.

Is there a name I can put in there that would work both for local development (when I'm not using the `app` container but am using the `db` container) and also work for when I run the app inside the `app` container?

I saw someone mention `host.docker.internal` but if I use that, when I try to run the app locally (not in the `app` container) it doesn't connect.

I have found that if I put my machines IP address in there, it fixes the issue - but is that the 'appropriate' way to do that? Should I be using docker networks or something else?

I realize I can just use something like this:

```
environment:
      # Override the default HOST names to point at the db container
      - HOST=db
```

But the library I am using reads the .env file at runtime and *overwrites* the OS level environment variables with the ones read in from the .env file - so that won't work for me. I realize that may not be ideal - but it's something we have found we need to do in certain cases when running many apps on the same machine that use slight variations in the values of the env variables.

all help is appreciated.

***TL;DR***: Is there an option other than the host computer IP address that works for an app to hit a docker db container both locally (on the host machine) as well as in a different docker container?